# Flushed Cache and lost database connection

Tags: magento-1.9, database

The last thing I did was `System/Cache Management/Flush Magento Cache`, now it appears database connectivity has been interrupted:

> ERR (3): Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known  in
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php
>   on line 129

Comment: I just realized the old database connection host etc is stuck in the database and is not reloading from local.xml. How/where does one reset these values directly in the  database?

Comment: try to export database and import it again with a name provided in the local.xml file!! This issue is related with the host name issue of course. Also, please check host name information in the local.xml file whether you are using proper host name to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin try to export database and import it again with a name provided in the local.xml file!! This issue is related with the host name issue of course. Also, please check host name information in the local.xml file whether you are using proper host name to connect to the database.